# scanf without additional arguments in C

Tags: c, scanf

Is it allowed to use `scanf(" ")` without additional arguments to ignore initial whitespaces?
I'm using `getchar()` to read the chars of a word, and I want to ignore the whitespaces before the word (whitespaces after are used to check the end of the word).
The code is the following, is it correct?

```
char *read_word() {
    int size = 2;
    int char_count = 0;
    char *s;
    char ch;

    s = mem_alloc(size);

    scanf(" ");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (char_count >= size) {
            s = mem_realloc(s, size++);
        }

        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') {
            s[char_count] = '\0';
            break;
        }

        s[char_count++] = ch;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely.....

Comment: Aside: `mem_realloc(s, size++);` --> `mem_realloc(s, ++size);`

Comment: Note: code can return `s` that lacks a null character.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks I've fixed (I forgot to write here), chux the format of the string I need to read ensures that the null char is added

Comment: Aside: fixed loop `for (;;) { int ch = getchar(); if (char_count >= size) { s = mem_realloc(s, ++size);  }  if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) {             s[char_count] = '\0'; break; }  s[char_count++] = ch;  }`

Comment: @raxell if `EOF` occurs, `s[char_count] = '\0';` does not.

Comment: chux was right, the string termination needs to be just before exit, but `size` may be one short. You started with `2`, but that does not keep up. Try `if (char_count >= size-1)`

Comment: @WeatherVane I've heard of answer invalidation (on Code Review) but not.. comment invalidation? If the mistake has nothing to do with the question why does it matter?

Comment: @Insane yup. Comments are meant to be for requesting clarification on a post; they become obsolete (and flagged as such) all the time.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yeah that's the most logical answer. I just don't see a reason why not to fix it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the definition of the `scanf()` function (*), emphasis mine:

> The format is composed of **zero or more** directives: one or more white-space characters, an ordinary multibyte character (neither `%` nor a white-space character), **or** a conversion specification.

[...]

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read.

So `scanf( " " );` is perfectly valid.

---

(*): ISO/IEC 9899:1999, 7.19.6.2 The `fscanf` function, section 3 and 5.

The other `*scanf` functions are defined in terms of this section.

Answer (score 9):

To add to the other answers, all of the following are valid:

```
scanf(" ");      // skip over whitespace
scanf("xyz");    // skip over the longest leading substring of "xyz" if present
                 // i.e. "xyz" or "xy" or "x"
scanf(" %*s ");  // skip over the first string and whitespace around it
```

Comment: appreciate to add additional knowledge with original answer - helpful

Answer (score 5):

The [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) says:

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives

...

> A directive is one of the following:
>
> • A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see
>   isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space,
>   including none, in the input.

...

so **yes**, it is a legal use of scanf.

---

If you're after efficiency:

```
int c;
while(isspace(c=getchar()) {;}
```

leads down a more efficient path, as getchar et. al. tend to have `_unlocked` counterparts, unlike `scanf`.

Comment: While not an issue in this case, I would be careful about relying on manpages. They usually do not distinguish clearly between what's ISO C, and what's POSIX -- and that *can* make a difference. So if the question is about whether something is legal or not "in C", standard trumps manpage. (And I'm not saying that just because I quoted it, but because I'm working on and with non-POSIX platforms from time to time.)

Comment: @DevSolar I agree. We posted pretty much simultaneously. I mightn't have posted mine if I'd seen yours first, but I think mine still has some value (=I'm getting points from it :D) so I'll keep it.

Comment: Note that to make your `getchar` example equivalent to `scanf(" ")` you will have to `ungetc(c, stdin)` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

I would instead try:

```
int skip = -1;
if (scanf(" %n", &skip)>=0 && skip>0)   {
  // you have skipped skip spaces
}
```

The >=0 test checks that `scanf` did not fail (e.g. because of EOF on stdin, or input error). The `skip>0` test checks that we have skipped at least one spacelike byte. The `%n` conversion specifier gives the number of parsed bytes.

Comment: The `>=0`test looks unneeded.  How does it help?

Comment: I was thinking that `skip` could not have changed if there was  EOF on stdin, or input error, so `skip` would retain its -1 value and then fail the `skip >0` test.  IAC, checking the return value of `scanf()` is something to encourage.

Comment: Well, if no space was skipped, my test is failing